# Fabric orderer not stating with Host IP - Multiple Node setup

Tags: tcp, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I have successfully installed fabric in 5 nodes. One for peer0, peer1, orderer0, kafka and client respectively

I am trying to start order with the following environment set in start-order.sh

```
ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=info \
ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=orderer0 \
ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file \
ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordererorg0/orderers/orderer0.ordererorg0/genesis.block \
ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererOrg0MSP \
ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordererorg0/orderers/orderer0.ordererorg0/msp \
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=false \
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordererorg0/orderers/orderer0.ordererorg0/tls/server.key \
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordererorg0/orderers/orderer0.ordererorg0/tls/server.crt \
ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ordererorg0/orderers/orderer0.ordererorg0/tls/ca.crt,/root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org0/peers/peer0.org0/tls/ca.crt,/root/bcnetwork/conf/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1/peers/peer2.org1/tls/ca.crt] \
CONFIGTX_ORDERER_BATCHTIMEOUT=1s \
CONFIGTX_ORDERER_ORDERERTYPE=kafka \
CONFIGTX_ORDERER_KAFKA_BROKERS=[kafka-zookeeper:9092] \
orderer
```

Host orderer0 I have set it in /etc/hosts which has no issue in it. But on executing, I get the following error

```
2018-02-19 12:53:31.597 UTC [orderer/main] main -> INFO 001 Starting orderer:


Version: 1.0.2
 Go version: go1.9
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2018-02-19 12:53:31.602 UTC [orderer/main] initializeGrpcServer -> CRIT 002 Failed to listen: listen tcp XX.XXX.XXX.XX:7050: bind: cannot assign requested address
r
```

Machine Config FYR

```
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
go version go1.9.4 linux/amd64
OS : Ubuntu 16.04
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
-e ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0 -e ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
```

orderer0 itself can't resolve to any address unless specified in your host.conf.

I have deployed the fabric on multiple nodes using docker swarm mode. You will need to create the swarm mode on one host and have other hosts join it as manager node. After that, you create an overlay network on the top of the swarm. This network is shared among all the nodes and thus allow containers to communicate with each other. You can see the complete tutorial at

[hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f)